# Profiling Django-Channels

Tags: python, django, websocket, django-channels

I've whipped up a proof-of-concept for a multiplayer game with a script to simulate a heavy load, but I'm not quite sure how to see how many streams of data it can handle.

For reference I'm sending ~1kb of data every 20ms for realtime multiplayer. I'm trying to determine what kind of load channels can take because I'm currently weighing channels vs nodejs or golang.

What's the best way to do this? Maybe average time between WebSocket received and broadcast as a proxy for server performance? So when that drops to some slower value performance is beginning to degrade?